# listbox items not clickable

Tags: silverlight, listbox

Is there a way to make a `listbox`'s items not clickable so there's no border around them when they're selected? Also is it possible to not make them selectable (when the mouse button is pressed while dragging over the control)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
</ItemsControl>
```